# How to find a class or function in a Python module?

Tags: python, module, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm trying to find the function or class definition of `gen_dataset_ops` in tensorflow, which has its sourcecode [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow). I find many places where it is imported like so:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_dataset_ops
```

But I can't find where it is defined, I'd expect to find something like:

```
def gen_dataset_ops(...):
  #Do something clever
  return
```

I don't quite understand the anatomy of python modules in general, so I'm probably missing some basics here,.. any hint is welcome!

Comment: Did you check the `tensorflow.python.ops` file for `gen_dataset_ops`?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: ops is a directory, no files named gen_dataset_ops and searching for it only reveals files that import it. Tnx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tensorflow.python.ops.gen_dataset_ops` is generated code. (That's why they put `gen` in front of the name.) You can't find it in the source repository because it's not *in* the source repository; it only comes into existence during the Tensorflow build process.

If you have Tensorflow installed, you should be able to find `gen_dataset_ops.py` under `tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py` in your Tensorflow installation.

Comment: Ah! Why is it machine generated?

Comment: @Bastiaan: It looks like they need to make a lot of very similar wrappers, and writing and maintaining all those wrappers by hand would be too much repetition.

Answer (score -3):

I would navigate to your python directory (this example is for a virtualenv on ubuntu):

`~/pyEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops.py` and open that file. In that file, use `Ctrl+F` and find the function you are looking for.

My answer assumes you know where your python environment is installed and that you installed `tensorflow` using `pip`

Comment: What `ops.py`? `tensorflow.python.ops` is a package.

Comment: @user2357112 [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py) URL shows the source code for ops.py. It doesn't seem to have the function OP is asking about. But in general, when you import a function in python it's contained in a module that is saved as *.py

Comment: That's `tensorflow.python.framework.ops`. Note the `framework` part.

Comment: My bad, I did not pay enough attention